# How do I remove AssignRoles and UnAssignRoles from ServiceStack API

Tags: servicestack

I'm using the Authentication feature in ServiceStack and configured the Auth plugin to use CredentialsAuthProvider. On the generated metadata page, ServiceStack shows the following operations:

- Auth
- AssignRoles
- UnAssignRoles

I'm only using the Auth operation, why I would like to remove the roles operations to avoid that the readers of this page get confused on how to use the API. Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you could do the following which will remove only AssignRoles and UnAssignRoles

```
AuthFeature authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() });

authFeature.IncludeAssignRoleServices = false; 

Plugins.Add(authFeature);
```

Answer (score 8):

When in doubt look to see if there's a description in the [Plugins wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins) or for this, the dedicated [Authentication page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization).

Each plugin has properties which override it's behavior, in this case just override it with the routes that are available:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession()) {
    IncludeAssignRoleServices = false
});
```

Which is a short-hand for:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] { ... },
    ServiceRoutes = new Dictionary<Type, string[]> {
      { typeof(AuthService), new[]{"/auth", "/auth/{provider}"} },
      //Omit the Un/AssignRoles service definitions here.
    }    
));
```

The [source code for the AuthFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/AuthFeature.cs#L44) is also useful to see the defaults of each property.